# jQuery widget, _on() method and Rails ajax callbacks

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-widgets

Rails provides different ajax events out of the box. (More info can be found here — https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax, source code can be found here — https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js#L125)

Now I have a custom widget which has two `_on()` methods defined. Here is code fragment that is relevant:

```
_create: function() {
  this._on(this.document, {
    "ajax:beforeSend #some-form": function(event, xhr, settings) {
      return console.log("Before send");
    }
  });

  this._on({
    // Event listeners for widget local events 
  });
}
```

I came to the point where I can have two `_on()` methods and both are working. First one listens to all events that happen inside `document` (so if I had something really trivial like `click *` event — it will work) and second one listens only to events fired within the widget.

If I bind rails callback directly to an element in the `$(document).ready` function everything works fine. Problems start when I try to add the event listener for rails `ajax:beforeSend`, `ajax:success` and other similar events into the first `_on()` method — it simply doesn't working.

Any ideas how to marry rails events to jquery-ui widget event listener? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll look at the code of [`_on()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js#L417) in jQuery UI you'll see that it uses regexp `/^(\w+)\s*(.*)$/` to get event name and selector:

```
var match = event.match( /^(\w+)\s*(.*)$/ ),
        eventName = match[1] + instance.eventNamespace,
        selector = match[2];
```

Apparently it sees your desired `ajax:beforeSend` event as just `ajax` and selector like `:beforeSend #some-form` and not triggering handler.

It is a common practive to make event names with colon inside nowadays so it may be a good idea to send pull request.

Meanwhile you could register global handlers for desired events and retrigger them with different names without colon inside.

Comment: Yay! Trigerring an event with different name did the trick! Thank!